# Dependency Injection by @Produce annotation in this example

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

this is a simple number-guess example to demonstrate dependency injection in Java EE 7. What I don't quite understand is the two injected fields in Game.java, "maxNumber" and "randomNumber". I understand that they can be injected because there are two @produce methods in Generator.java, @Produce int next() and @Produce int getMaxNumber().

However, the method name "next()" doesn't match "randumNumber" injected in Game.java. How does this work？

Also, I tried changing "getMaxNumber()" to something else "getMMMaxNumber()" in Generator.java. The program still works fine. So, I really don't understand how these two fields are injected into Game.java from Generator.java.

Please help understand this. Thanks really in advance.

Game.java

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.numberguess;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Game implements Serializable {
/**
 * The number that the user needs to guess
 */
private int number;

/**
 * The users latest guess
 */
private int guess;

/**
 * The smallest number guessed so far (so we can track the valid guess range).
 */
private int smallest;

/**
 * The largest number guessed so far
 */
private int biggest;

/**
 * The number of guesses remaining
 */
private int remainingGuesses;

/**
 * The maximum number we should ask them to guess
 */
@Inject
@MaxNumber
private int maxNumber;

/**
 * The random number to guess
 */
@Inject
@Random
Instance<Integer> randomNumber;

public Game() {
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public int getGuess() {
    return guess;
}

public void setGuess(int guess) {
    this.guess = guess;
}

public int getSmallest() {
    return smallest;
}

public int getBiggest() {
    return biggest;
}

public int getRemainingGuesses() {
    return remainingGuesses;
}


@PostConstruct
public void reset() {
    this.smallest = 0;
    this.guess = 0;
    this.remainingGuesses = 10;
    this.biggest = maxNumber;
    this.number = randomNumber.get();
}
}
```

Generator.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ApplicationScoped
public class Generator implements Serializable {

private java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

private int maxNumber = 100;

java.util.Random getRandom() {
    return random;
}

@Produces
@Random
int next() {
    // a number between 1 and 100
    return getRandom().nextInt(maxNumber - 1) + 1;
}

@Produces
@MaxNumber
int getMaxNumber() {
    return maxNumber;
}
}
```

MaxNumber.java

```
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface MaxNumber {

}
```

Random.java

```
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface Random {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injection is not done by method name, but rather the two values are distinguished by their **qualifiers** `@Random` and `@MaxNumber`.  The respective method names of the `@Produce`-annotated methods are not relevant, they only need to return a matching type.